# Read in year, DOY and microsecond data as datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a data file formatted like this:

```
year  doy    milliseconds    data
2000  103    272220          1.123
2000  103    373058          1.342
2000  103    471764          0.743
2000  103    573509          1.666
2000  103    664624          1.736
2000  103    758810          1.762
2000  103    951634          1.888
2000  103   1071637          1.444
2000  103   1156676          1.001
```

that I want to read in using python. I first convert into microseconds using awk so that the datetime module can read the data but it isn't able to.  The data is read in fine but the dates are returned as 'nan'.  I've also tried converting to seconds and rounding up to integer values and the same for minutes.  I think maybe I need to read in the data and then change the milliseconds into hour:min:sec to use datetime but I wanted to check here first if there is a better way or if I am using datetime incorrectly.  Thanks for your help!

Here is my code:

```
datefunc = lambda x: mdates.date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y %j %S'))
data = np.genfromtxt(sat_filenames,delimiter=(13,10),converters={0:datefunc},
                     names='Date, Var')
```

I resorted to stating the delimiters by space number because I couldn't get '\t' to work - but let me know if you can!

Comment: Is column 3 really milliseconds or microsecond as in title? Does the `data` field relate to the final datetime? See my answer offered below.

Comment: Sorry the title should be milliseconds, the date is given by year, doy, and milliseconds and the last column is the data for that date e.g rainfall in cm or something.  Does your solution still apply?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your feedback, no problem, yes my answer creates datetime only using milliseconds, I've edited my answer to reflect the output, I believe only you can confirm if the answer still applies. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
f = r"df2dt.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True)
td_ms = pd.to_timedelta(df['milliseconds'], unit='ms')
td_D = pd.to_timedelta(df['doy'] - 1, unit='D')
date_str = df['year'].astype(str)
date = pd.to_datetime(date_str, format="%Y", yearfirst=True)
date_time = date + td_D + td_ms
data = df['data']
print(date_time, data)
```

`df2dt.txt` is your data in a file.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the pandas package, instead just using datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Using plain old Python's `datetime`:

```
import datetime

dates = []

with open('datafile.txt','r') as fp:
    fp.readline()
    lines = fp.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip('\n').split()
    data = float(line[3])
    line = map(int, line[0:3])
    line.append(data)
    dates.append(line)

print '{0:<32}{1}'.format('datetime', 'data')
for dt in dates:
    date = datetime.datetime(dt[0], 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=dt[1], milliseconds=dt[2])
    print '{0}\t{1}'.format(date, dt[3])
```

Output:

```
datetime                    data
2000-04-13 00:04:32.220000  1.123
2000-04-13 00:06:13.058000  1.342
2000-04-13 00:07:51.764000  0.743
2000-04-13 00:09:33.509000  1.666
2000-04-13 00:11:04.624000  1.736
2000-04-13 00:12:38.810000  1.762
2000-04-13 00:15:51.634000  1.888
2000-04-13 00:17:51.637000  1.444
2000-04-13 00:19:16.676000  1.001
```

The title mentions microseconds yet question refers to milliseconds, so change the parameter passed to timedelta as necessary. Also, I wasn't sure what the `data` column refers to or how to include it in the date or time since the question does include milliseconds. If this answer needs modification to match your desired output, note in a comment and I'll update. Otherwise it should be fairly straightforward to modify this to get the exact desired output.

Notice how code only using python's native `datetime` module is almost as concise as the pandas solution, perhaps just as readable, and would be the same if my code was more "pythonic".

Anyways, Hope this helps!